# How to add an escape sequence for an IFS character?

Tags: linux, bash

I have an IFS as highlighted below in a shell script.

```
IFS=',' read -ra CONFIG_PAIRS <<< "$CONFIGS"
for CONFIG_PAIR in "${CONFIG_PAIRS[@]}"
```

I would like to know if there is an escape sequence to overcome the above IFS when I read the string. For instance when I read the below, I would want the shell to ignore the second instance of the character ' **,** ' (i.e., the character comma). Is this possible, or is there a work around. Can anyone please suggest me?

```
 "master_slave_mode:true,load_balance_mode:'true,false'"
```

Comment: bash is not smart enough to parse CSV or JSON. Use a proper language-specific parser.

Comment: @glennjackman
But I am unable to add solve the above problem even without yaml/json. Is there an escape sequence in that case.